# How to retrieve Firebase images to ImageView?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my Firebase Realtime Database structure:

[image]

I want to retrieve each and every image in a child(images1,images2,images3,images4 are the child names)

```
private void loadmybanners1() {
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("BannerImages");
        ref.orderByChild("images2").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    final String myImg1 = "" + ds.child("image").getValue();


                    try{
                        Picasso.get().load(myImg1).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(ban2Iv, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Exception e) {
                                Picasso.get().load(myImg1).into(ban2Iv);
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        ban2Iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_image);
                    }
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

I have used this code to retrieve the image2. But from that, I can only retrieve the images1 child data. What are the modifications to do?

Comment: you just need to remove the orderByChild("images2") from your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to retrieve each and every image in a child

To get each and every child within your `BannerImages` node, there is no need to use a query, you can simply use a `DatabaseReference`, as in the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference bannerImagesRef = rootRef.child("BannerImages");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String myImg1 = dataSnapshot.child("images1").child("image").getValue(String.class);
        Picasso.get().load(myImg1)
        String myImg2 = dataSnapshot.child("images2").child("image").getValue(String.class);
        Picasso.get().load(myImg2)

        //And so on for the other images3, images4, and images5 children
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
bannerImagesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Just took a closer look and I made a change. I have added the call to `.child("images1")`, before `.child("image")`. Now it should work perfectly fine.

Comment: Now it worked. Could you please tell me how can I implement those 4 images in a view flipper to auto slide in the image view. A releavant link also appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, this question cannot be answer in a comment. So I recommend you post a new fresh question so me or other Firebase developers can take a look at it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63370043/how-to-retrieve-firebase-images-in-a-viewflipper I have created that. can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
```

After getting Url from Firebase.Just Use below line

```
Glide.with(context).load(Firbase Url).into(imageView);
```